# VB.NET and Access DataBase Trends

Tags: database, vb.net

This might be a simple question and answer but I am just stuck. =(
Lets say we have a Access Database with items ordered by users saved

```
ID | Product Number | Product Name
-----------------------------------
1  | 00001          | Some Name 1
-----------------------------------
2  | 00001          | Some Name 1
-----------------------------------
3  | 00002          | Some Name 2
-----------------------------------
4  | 00003          | Some Name 3
-----------------------------------
5  | 00003          | Some Name 3
-----------------------------------
```

What I'd like is the code to

- Open the db ***<-- Got that part down.***
- Read the table with the said data listed above. ***<--Got this down***
- **Need Help :** Report the most common Product number ordered.

  I have messed with a few idea's but with no success. The data will be reported to a listview.

Thanks..

Comment: how do you determine what is the most common product number ordered? is it just the one that has the most records related to it?

Comment: If I understand you answer, yes. EX 00001 00003 would be first then 00002

Comment: So, your output will just be a list of products, ordered descending by the number of times it appears in the table?

Comment: Yes. that is correct. =)

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET or Linq ?

Comment: does this help?     Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim myCmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim myDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim myDR As OleDbDataReader

Comment: VB.NET as in visual studio 2013 visual basic

Comment: Just as a general comment, this table layout is not normalized. I invite you to learn about database normalization.

Comment: If you are intent on reading the whole dataset back, just create a dictionary object, populate the key with the order number and then tally in the value field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT([Product Number]) AS CNT, [Product Number] FROM TableXXX GROUP BY [Product Number] ORDER BY COUNT([Product Number]) DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just include most of this in your query to the database, like this (where t1 is your table name):

```
SELECT [Product Number], count(*) as TotalOrders
FROM t1
GROUP BY [product number]
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

That will automatically count and order the Product Numbers.

Comment: This worked.. I keep forgetting SQL can do this also.. Thanks. Now with adding it to the listview.